# Habilitar input type="file" quando input type="checkbox" == true

Tags: javascript, html

Estou com dificuldade em fazer uma coisa que aparentemente deve ser bem simples, eu preciso que uma input do tipo file fique desabilitada/invisível até que o usuário marque uma input do tipo checkbox que por padrão virá desabilitada.

Eis aqui minha tentativa:

```js
function HabilitarUpload(Opcao1, UploadOpcao1) 
{
    document.getElementById(UploadOpcao1).disabled = !Opcao1.checked;
}
```

```html
<label class="container">OPÇÃO 1
    <input type="checkbox" id="Opcao1" onclick="HabilitarUpload(Opcao1, UploadOpcao1);">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<p>TEXTO UPLOAD OPÇÃO 1
    <input type="file" name="img" id="UploadOpcao1" disabled="true">
</p>
```

Também gostaria de saber se/como eu poderia fazer com que o texto que vem antes do input do tipo file (TEXTO UPLOAD OPÇÃO 1) apareça somente quando a checkbox estiver marcada.

Comment: Você gostou das respostas? A melhor forma de agradecer a quem te ajudou é assinalando "aceite" na melhor resposta e votando em todas que te ajudaram. Assim você garante que quem escreveu a resposta receba algo em troca, além de tornar o site mais limpo e útil para todo mundo.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que eu percebi quer esconder esse input file. Para isso pode utilizar o atributo `hidden`. Sem querer alterar muito o seu código na sua forma basta adicionar ou remover o atributo `hidden` quando estiver checked ou não, respetivamente.

Veja a funcionar em baixo:

```js
function HabilitarUpload() 
{
    if (document.getElementById('Opcao1').checked) 
    {
        document.getElementById('upload1').removeAttribute("hidden");
    } 
    else 
    {
        document.getElementById('upload1').setAttribute("hidden", "true");
    }
}
```

```html
<label class="container">OPÇÃO 1
    <input type="checkbox" id="Opcao1" onclick="HabilitarUpload();">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<p id="upload1" hidden="true">TEXTO UPLOAD OPÇÃO 1
    <input type="file" name="img" id="UploadOpcao1">
</p>
```

PS: Note que você tem ai muitos problemas. As tags `label` e `p` não devem ser usadas para agrupar outras tags. Para esse efeito deve usar a tag [`div`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div).

Answer (score 0):

O exemplo abaixo po de ajudar a resolver seu problema, caso seja só um input que você queira mostrar.

```js
const option1 = document.getElementById('Opcao1'); // Seleciona o checkbox
let UploadOpcao1 = document.querySelector('.UploadOpcao1'); // A div com o input

// Adiciona o evento de click
option1.addEventListener('click', function(e){

    // Verifica se o checkbox foi selecionado
    const isActive = e.target.checked

    // Mostra o input de upload
    UploadOpcao1.style.display = 'block';
})
```

```html
     <label class="container">OPÇÃO 1
        <input type="checkbox" id="Opcao1">
    </label>

    <p style="display: none" class="UploadOpcao1">TEXTO UPLOAD OPÇÃO 1
        <input type="file" name="img" disabled="true">
    </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Um pouco mais simples:

```js
function clique() {
  var e = document.getElementById("imagem");
  e.removeAttribute("disabled");
}
```

```html
<p>Checkbox: <input type="checkbox" name="check" onclick="clique()"></p>
<p>Imagem: <input id="imagem" type="file" name="imagem" disabled="disabled"></p>
```

Observe que este código somente habilita o campo input quando o checkbox é clicado. Se precisar desabilitá-lo novamente caso o checkbox seja limpo, é necessário adaptar o mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode verificar o evento de `change` utilizando o jQuery para sempre que o checkbox mudar de " estado ", ele habilitar ou desabilitar o input. Desta maneira:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#Opcao1").on('change', function(){
            if($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $("#UploadOpcao1").prop('disabled', false);
            } else {
                $("#UploadOpcao1").prop('disabled', true);
            }
        })
    })
```

```html
 <label class="container">OPÇÃO 1
     <input type="checkbox" id="Opcao1">
     <span class="checkmark"></span>
 </label>
 <p>TEXTO UPLOAD OPÇÃO 1
     <input type="file" name="img" id="UploadOpcao1" disabled="true">
 </p>
 <script
 src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
 integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
 crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```